# modal views with angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I would like to create a modal view with angular, but I cannot find any resource online. Can anyone point me into the right direction?

What I mean by modal view is like when clicking on a photo on facebook: it will open on top of the page so that clicking in the background will bring back to the main view.

Of course, I am not looking for css details on how to achieve the lightbox effect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about a directive?

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap you can use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After experimenting with various options, including the Angular-UI-bootstrap modals, I have come to a pretty satisfying custom solution that provides all functionality you'd want from a modal:

```
<div class="myBackdrop" ng-show="flag.modalOpen" ng-click="closeModal()"></div>
<div class="myModal" ng-show="flag.modalOpen">
  ...
</div>
```

where

```
// just a boolean flag
$scope.flag = {
  modalOpen: false
}

$scope.closeModal = function() {
  // optionally do something beforehand
  $scope.flag.modalOpen = false;
}
```

Then all you need is the CSS for `.myBackdrop` and `.myModal`

Comment: pretty good solution that does not need bootstrap! is there a way to combine this with routes as well? so it can have a state and it can be saved as bookmark as well?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this open-source modal(in AngularJS) from ui-bootstrap. It takes advantage of modularity through directives and covers many usability features. This would be a great reference point to build a re-usable solution, even without the Bootstrap CSS.
https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal

Comment: that's a problem if you don't use bootstrap!

Comment: The important part to pay attention to is the file modal.js in the above link. This file contains a tested solution for re-usable modals around your site. Get familiar with this code. It will provide a useful reference when building your own. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap for a comprehensive solution.

You can also build it yourself for simple solutions using `ng-show` on a modal element :-)

Comment: that's a problem if you don't use bootstrap!

Comment: You can actually override the templates on the bootstrap project and make it use any CSS you want.  That's the "philosophy" of that project - bootstrap by default, but the logic isn't coupled to the DOM layout so any css will work.